# Can Firejails protect against malicious links?

Tags: linux, keyloggers, trojan

I would like to ask, if Firejails on Linux, protects when clicking a malicious link in the browser e.g. from downloading a keylogger or a trojan.

Comment: Downloading malware is not dangerous as long it is not executed. And jail breakouts are unlikely but they exist as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

Firejail is a sandbox for process execution. While it could be used to limit network activity, it has no way to distinguish between a safe and a malicious link. So it does not prevent downloading it.

If the browser is executed inside the firejail and if the jail is configured to not share any data with outside the jail, then the jail can be used to limit the impact, i.e. keep anything malicious inside the jail.